# Unable to get location of my phone in app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am building app in Android Studio that will access user location. Below provided is the code I am using. I am using my phone itself as an emulator. I have granted ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_INTERNET in the manifest XML file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locMan;
    LocationListener locList;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locList);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locMan = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locList = new LocationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Here I am trying to make toast of my location. In place of 'getApplicationContext()' , I had passed 'MainActivity' but it also don't work.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s)
            {

            }
        };
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        else
        {
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locList);
        }
    }
}
```

What can be done ? Is there any issue with my GPS ?

Comment: _"Is there any issue with my GPS ?"_ It probably won't work indoors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the android version you are using, you might need to use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, too. Try adding it to your manifest and requesting the permisison in your activity.

I once wrote a working class to constantly track a devices location.

```
private static LocationManager locationManager=null;
private static LocationListener locationListener=null;

public static void startTrackingLocation(final Context context, final LocationChangedListener listener) {
    startTrackingLocation(context, listener, 0.5, 1);
}
/**
 * Location gets requested periodically, and a call on abstract listener.onLocationChanged(Location l)
 * is performed if distance between locations is > distance
 * @param context   context to gather the location from
 * @param listener  listens to location changes
 * @param minutes   interval between the location requests
 * @param distance  minimal distance to trigger onLocationChanged(Location l)
 */
public static void startTrackingLocation(@NotNull final Context context, @NotNull final LocationChangedListener listener, final double minutes, final int distance) {
    initLocationManager(context);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            listener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
    };

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, (int)(minutes*60000), distance, locationListener);
    } catch (SecurityException ignored) { }
}

private static void initLocationManager(@NotNull final Context context) {
    if (null==locationManager) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void stopTrackingLocation() {
    if (null!=locationManager && null!=locationListener) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}

public static Location getLocation(final Context context) {
    initLocationManager(context);
    Location locationGPS=null, locationNet=null;
    try {
        locationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        locationNet = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (SecurityException ignored) { }

    if (null != locationNet) {
        return locationNet;
    }
    return locationGPS;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static double distance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2) {
    final double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2))
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
    dist = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(dist)) * 60 * 1850 ; // 1 degree is 111km 111/60=1.85
    return (dist);
}
```

The LocationChangedListener class is an abstract class I wrote to catch the event where location was changed.

The code is very simple:

```
 public abstract void onLocationChanged(Location location);
```

In your activity:

```
LocationChangedListener listener = new LocationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            MainActivity.this.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    };
```

This is fully working on my android device, you may give it a try. Besides, the function Location getLocation(final Context context) may be left out as it only gives you devices location at given time.

I used the same permissions in the manifest. This should also work for you.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but still, the issue remains the same. Android version of my phone OREO. Should I try a different setting?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've notice is that you only have the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission and also using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`. This instruct the app to only use the GPS to obtain position and not the optimized way, a combination of GPS, Mobile Network and WiFi Networks.

And I'm guessing as you are coding you are indoors. The GPS needs sky visibility to work, so maybe it can not get the signal from the Satellites. You could try putting it next to the window and might work.

But if you are not required to strictly use the GPS only, change it to use every posible provider.

Comment: locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locList);
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager, WIFI_SERVICE, 0, 0, locList);
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager, NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE, 0,0, locList);      // NOW I AM USING WIFI_SERVICE AND NETWORK_STATE_SERVICE AND IAM GETTING THIS ERROR //- error: cannot find symbol
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager, WIFI_SERVICE, 0, 0, locList);
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable LocationManager